# What is the difference between updating an object with a new object against updating its properties?

Tags: c#, class, object, .net-4.5

Say the follow Class:

```
public class MyClas
{
    public MyClass(uint a, string b, uint c, bool d)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
        C = c;
        D = d;
    }

    internal void Update(uint a, string b, uint c, bool d)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
        C = c;
        D = d;
    }

    public uint A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public uint C { get; set; }
    public bool D { get; set; }
}
```

We have MyClass as a static variable somewhere in the project making it accessible everywhere.

```
public static MyClass NamedItLikeThis { get; set; }
```

Then we have a method being called every X milliseconds and it updates `NamedItLikeThis` like this:

```
public void UpdateSeveralThings()
{
    NamedItLikeThis = new MyClass(1, "test", 2, true);
}
```

My question is:

- What is the difference between updating `NamedItLikeThis` with a new object like the above example against instantiating it once with a new object and then using that object Update method to keep it up to date like the below example?

  ```
  public void UpdateSeveralThings()
  {
      if (NamedItLikeThis == null)
      {
          NamedItLikeThis = new MyClass(1, "test", 2, true);
      }
      else
      {
          NamedItLikeThis.Update(2, "update", 3, false);
      }
  }
  ```
- What is the correct approach to update an object in this circumstances?

Comment: one is updating a shared object, that others might have a reference to, affecting them as well.  the other is creating a new object, which won't affect anyone else who has a reference to the old object.  The "what is the correct approach" part is going to be very subjective, based on what you're actually doing.

Comment: @JohnGardner indeed after reading David's answer it made realize my sample was rather superficial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what the object semantically *means* in the system.  Without knowing that, there is no approach more correct than the other.

If the object is simply a data structure and it nothing more than the collection of its values, there is no difference.  In fact, in some cases you might even make simple data structures immutable so that they can only be replaced with new instances and not directly modified.

But the point is that an object which is nothing more than a wrapper for data values is identified entirely by the sum of those values.  Two instances with the same values are otherwise indistinguishable from one another, so semantically the two approaches make no difference.

On the other hand, if the object is a rich model of sorts, with internal state and inner workings, then replacing one instance with another implies *destroying* something and *creating* something, which may have other implications.  It's a *different* object, even if its properties are the same.

As an analogy, picture some mundane real-world object.  Like a toy ball.  If you destroy it and create a new one of the same dimensions, does it really matter?  Probably not.

However, consider a person.  If you destroy a person and create a new one with the same characteristics (eye color, hair color, etc.), does it matter?  Yes.  It's a different person.  Some outwardly visible attributes are the same, but the implications of the action go deeper than that.

---

Now, on a *technical* level, under the hood, there is a difference in how the values are managed in memory and whatnot.  But it's *probably* trivial for most intents and purposes.  The new object is a pointer to a new location in memory, so any other pointers to the new or old location may behave unexpectedly if you thought they were going to continue to be the same object.

For example...

```
var x = new MyClass(1);
var y = x;

// later
x.Update(2);
```

In the above code, `y` is also updated.  There was only ever one instance of `MyClass`.  However...

```
var x = new MyClass(1);
var y = x;

// later
x = new MyClass(2);
```

In the above code, `y` is *not* updated.  There are now *two* instances of `MyClass`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. So in the event of me, having a real person, the update method would be the correct way specially if I have person's states like moving, idle, jumping or inner classes that further define that person, right?

Comment: @Guapo: I would say yes. (Though it's possible some edge case outside of this simplified scenario exists.) The idea being that a second instance is somehow identified differently than the first, even if its attributes are the same. Just to keep the semantics of a system clear, I'd probably only "destroy and create" at a service boundary, such as transmitting over a web service or persisting into a database. In that case the object is essentially serialized to its attributes and reconstructed at another place and time. (Ala "transporters" in Star Trek. Though I argue they kill the person...)

Comment: I am sure it could partially leave some of your parts intact in the process even tough I can't vouch for safety or guarantee which parts will be chosen. Thanks for clearly that up for me very appreciated.